# ASP.NET MVC Json 404 Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, http-status-code-404

Similar questions have been asked over and over but for some reason none of the things I have tried have worked.  I have an ajax application and when the user request an invalid url I would like to return a JsonResult that looks something like this:

```
[ error: true, status: 404, message: 'The requested page could not be found... or some other message... ']
```

I don't want the user to just be redirected to the error page defined in the web.config file as that would take them out of the ajax application.

I have tried the following things:

- Custom HandleErrorAttribute - Turns out these only handle 500 errors due to exceptions thrown by my code
- Custom FilterAttribute that extends FilterAttribute and implements IExceptionFilter - Same issue as before
- Override HandleUnknownAction in the Base Controller - Couldn't figure out how to return a JsonResult from the method
- Added a catch all route - My other routes are being used before the catch all route is found

Any thoughts would be appreciate.

Comment: How can your other routes be used if it's a 404 you are expecting?

Comment: The url /NonExistantController/NonExistantAction/ still matches the stock route /{Controller}/{Action}/{id} so that route is used before the catch all route of {*url}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> •Override HandleUnknownAction in the Base Controller - Couldn't figure out how to return a JsonResult from the method

```
new JsonResult() 
  { 
    Data = your_404_data,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, 
  }.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
```

Updated to include the JsonRequestBehavior - which you will need.

For requests which don't match an existing controller or resource you have two choices - to ditch the standard catch-all route `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` and replace it with one that sends the request to a fixed controller that returns this 404-like response that you want.

Or use standard Asp.Net error handling to redirect to a route that will do the same thing.  Personally I prefer this solution because it means that you don't have to code loads of routes into your global.

Comment: Works great.  What about an unknown controller though?

Comment: @NickOlsen - have updated my answer; basically either ditch the default route for a 404 catch-all; or use Asp.Net custom error responses to redirect to a controller that returns this response.  If it's IIS 7, which I'm sure it is, you can also use IIS custom errors in the web.config to do the same thing.